# In fragment, restore an object that contains a list of another object with Parcelable implementation

Tags: android, android-fragments, parcelable

I have a `Car` class implements `Parcelable`:

```
public class Car implements Parcelable {
    private long id;
    private String model;

    public Car(long id, String model) {
       this.id = id;
       this.model = model;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(this.id);
        dest.writeString(this.model);

    }

    private Car(Parcel in) {
        this.id = in.readLong();
        this.model = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Car> CREATOR = new Creator<Car>() {
        @Override
        public Car createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Car(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Car[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Car[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Then, I have a `Store` class which holds a list of cars, it also implements `Parcelable`:

```
public class Store implements Parcelable {
   private List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();

   public List<Car> getCarList() {
        return carList;
    }
   public void setCarList(List<Car> cars) {
        carList = cars;
   }

   @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
       dest.writeTypedList(this.carList);
    }

    private Store(Parcel in) {
      in.readTypedList(carList, Car.CREATOR);
    }

    public static final Creator<Store> CREATOR = new Creator<Store>() {
        @Override
        public Store createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Store(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Store[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Store[size];
        }
    };
}
```

In a Fragment, I try to restore the `Store` instance named `myStore`, including the list of cars in it:

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {
   private Store myStore;

   @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(MY_STORE)) {
            myStore = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(MY_STORE);
            // PROBLEM IS HERE:
            // when runtime hit here, the restored myStore contains one car but has id with weird long value and null in model field. WHY?
        } else {
            // initialize myStore with car list (only one car)
            Car myCar = new Car(1, "BMW X1");
            List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
            cars.add(myCar);

            myStore = new Store();
            myStore.setCarList(cars);
        }
    }

   @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        if(myStore != null) {
            outState.putParcelable(MY_STORE, myStore);
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

}
```

Problem occur when in `MyFragment`, code tries to restore `myStore` in `onCreate()`. At runtime , the restored `myStore` does contain one car in a list, but the car in that list has id with weird long value (e.g. `28429333427126393`) and `null` in `model` field. WHY?  What did I do wrong? How to restore an object contains a list of another object?

Comment: I don't think your code compiles. `myStore = savedInstanceState.getString(MY_STORE)` would fail as you're assigning a `String` to a field of type `Store`.

Comment: Thanks, that's my typo only, updated to ```getParcelable(MY_STORE)```

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually occurs when your `carList` instance **was null** so you wrote a null object in parcelable and try to read from it.

One of the options is that you initialize your list when it's null and then write it in parcelable. Using this case your list will always have a reference after restoration which might not be what you're looking for.

The other approach is to write a byte value before writing your list into parcelable indicating that your list was null or you should expect some value from it. For this case I'm using [this helper class](https://gist.github.com/keyboardr/5563038) which solved my own problem. Based on my needs, I have made some improvements. Here is my version if you'd prefer to use it:

```
public class ParcelableUtils {
    public static void write(Parcel dest, String string) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (string == null ? 0 : 1));
        if (string != null) {
            dest.writeString(string);
        }
    }

    public static String readString(Parcel source) {
        if (source.readByte() == 1) {
            return source.readString();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void write(Parcel dest, Parcelable parcelable, int flags) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (parcelable == null ? 0 : 1));
        if (parcelable != null) {
            dest.writeParcelable(parcelable, flags);
        }
    }

    public static <T extends Parcelable> T readParcelable(Parcel source) {
        if (source.readByte() == 1) {
            return source.readParcelable(null);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static <T extends Parcelable> T readParcelable(Parcel source, Class objectClass) {
        if (source.readByte() == 1) {
            return source.readParcelable(objectClass.getClassLoader());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void write(Parcel dest, Map<String, String> strings) {
        if (strings == null) {
            dest.writeInt(-1);
        }
        {
            dest.writeInt(strings.keySet().size());
            for (String key : strings.keySet()) {
                dest.writeString(key);
                dest.writeString(strings.get(key));
            }
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, String> readStringMap(Parcel source) {
        int numKeys = source.readInt();
        if (numKeys == -1) {
            return null;
        }
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numKeys; i++) {
            String key = source.readString();
            String value = source.readString();
            map.put(key, value);
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static <T extends Parcelable> void write(Parcel dest, Map<String, T> objects, int flags) {
        if (objects == null) {
            dest.writeInt(-1);
        } else {
            dest.writeInt(objects.keySet().size());
            for (String key : objects.keySet()) {
                dest.writeString(key);
                dest.writeParcelable(objects.get(key), flags);
            }
        }
    }

    public static <T extends Parcelable> Map<String, T> readParcelableMap(Parcel source) {
        int numKeys = source.readInt();
        if (numKeys == -1) {
            return null;
        }
        HashMap<String, T> map = new HashMap<String, T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numKeys; i++) {
            String key = source.readString();
            T value = source.readParcelable(null);
            map.put(key, value);
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static void write(Parcel dest, URL url) {
        dest.writeString(url.toExternalForm());
    }

    public static URL readURL(Parcel source) {
        try {
            return new URL(source.readString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void write(Parcel dest, Date date) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (date == null ? 0 : 1));
        if (date != null) {
            dest.writeLong(date.getTime());
        }
    }

    public static Date readDate(Parcel source) {
        if (source.readByte() == 1) {
            return new Date(source.readLong());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static <T extends java.lang.Enum<T>> void write(Parcel dest, java.lang.Enum<T> enu) {
        if (enu == null) {
            dest.writeString("");
        } else {
            dest.writeString(enu.name());
        }
    }

    public static <T extends java.lang.Enum<T>> T readEnum(Parcel dest, Class<T> clazz) {
        String name = dest.readString();
        if ("".equals(name)) {
            return null;
        }
        return java.lang.Enum.valueOf(clazz, name);
    }

    public static void write(Parcel dest, boolean bool) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (bool ? 1 : 0));
    }

    public static boolean readBoolean(Parcel source) {
        return source.readByte() == 1;
    }

    public static <T extends Parcelable> void write(Parcel dest,
                                                    List<T> fields, int flags) {
        if (fields == null) {
            dest.writeInt(-1);
        } else {
            dest.writeInt(fields.size());
            for (T field : fields) {
                dest.writeParcelable(field, flags);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T extends Parcelable> List<T> readParcelableList(
            Parcel source) {
        int size = source.readInt();
        if (size == -1) {
            return null;
        }
        ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            list.add((T) source.readParcelable(null));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.